# Optimizing a Fortran subroutine

Tags: optimization, random, fortran

I've written a minimal implementation for the fast [xoroshiro128plus pseudo-random number generator](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/) in Fortran to replace the intrinsic `random_number`. This implementation is quite fast (4X faster than `random_number`) and the quality is good enough for my purposes, I don't use it in cryptography applications.

My question is how can I optimize this subroutine to get the last drop of performance from my compiler, even 10% improvement is appreciated. This subroutine is to be used in tight loops inside long simulations. I'm interested more in generating a single random number at a time and not big vectors or nD arrays at once.

Here is a test program to give you some context about how my subroutine is used:

```
program test_xoroshiro128plus
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: n = 10000
   real*8  :: A(n,n)
   integer :: i, j, t0, t1, count_rate, count_max

   call system_clock(t0, count_rate, count_max)
   do j = 1,n
      do i = 1,n
         call drand128(A(i,j))
      end do
   end do
   ! call drand128(A)  ! works also with 2D 
   call system_clock(t1)

   print *, "Time :", real(t1-t0)/count_rate
   print *, "Mean :", sum(A)/size(A), char(10), A(1:2,1:3)

 contains

   impure elemental subroutine drand128(r)
      real*8, intent(out) :: r
      integer*8 :: s0 = 113, s1 = 19937
      s1 = xor(s0,s1)
      s0 = xor(xor(ior(ishft(s0,55), ishft(s0,-9)),s1), ishft(s1,14))
      s1 = ior(ishft(s1,36), ishft(s1,-28))
      r = ishft(s0+s1, -1) / 9223372036854775808.d0
   end 

end program
```

Comment: Could you share your compilation and and options?

Comment: I fear this question is far too broad to be answered here.  As you claim to have already decent performance, anything else we can say will be have to be based on much you don't mention.  For example, what architecture are you using, with which compiler and which compiler flags?  What criteria do you have for the accuracy of any optimization-driven changes?  And so on.

Comment: I use `ifort` most of the time on Windows 10, the machine has a decent Intel CPU which supports 64bit operations. Other than linking with MKL and sometimes enabling /Qparallel I don't have any specific constraints on accuracy. May be `ifort /fast /Qmkl /Qpar main.f90` are normal usage flags.

Comment: @AboAmmar, your code may work for your needs, but it isn't a replacement for random_number nor does it appear to be a PRNG.  It will generate the same sequence of numbers (ie., there is no randomness) upon each execution of the program.

Comment: @Steve -- * It will generate the same sequence of numbers (i.e., there is no randomness) upon each execution of the program* and so do `random_number` unless you issue `random_seed()`, e.g., (works only with `ifort`), I can easily seed my generator as well. My point is mostly about speed, I could use the PRNG that comes with MKL, but it works best only with long vectors, I need a single rand at a time. Besides, my `drand128` has the same speed as MKL's `vdrnguniform` without the headache of including big modules or setting up weird parameters.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark -- Yes, I used to generate a temporary long vector of rands and pull one rand at a time like `temp(i)`, but this strategy didn't prove efficient in either runtime or memory usage. I speak about MKL's `vdrnguniform` of course, the fastest that I tried.

Comment: @AboAmmar,  The behavior of `random_number` when called without calling `random_seed` first is processor dependent behavior.  The Fortran processor may initialize the PRNG use by `random_number` by a fixed seed or it may initialize it with some random seed (if `random_seed` isn't called).  Your point about speed in comparison to `random_number` is moot if your function only implements a portion of what `random_number` does.

Comment: @Steve, All PRNGs are not truly random, and seeding is not important for my applications, sometimes repeatability is needed more. Also, look at the numbers in [the linked page](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/), `xoroshiro128+` is not only one of the fastest PRNGs, but also one of highest quality ones. Fortran's intrinsic uses the Mersenne Twister algorithm which is 1/4 the speed of `xoroshiro128+`

Comment: @boAmmar, I never said anything about truly random numbers.  I simply corrected your statement that `random_number` always returns the same sequence if `random_seed` isn't called first.  That is processor dependent behavior.  No, Fortran's intrinsic does not use the Mersenne Twister.  Each Fortran vendor uses whatever algorithm the vendor think is best.  gfortran used MT a long time ago, and I ripped that out because of its poor quality.  gfortran then used 4 independent KISS generators (KISS as in Marsaglia prng).  gfortran now uses one of Vigna's xorshift prng.

Comment: I think your benchmark is a little silly. You generate numbers, ok. This algorithm is shorter and lower quality than the intrinsic, but attend your needs, ok. There isn't much more to do at Fortran-level with the code you presented, than maybe specializing it for parallel execution. Now, if you present a snippet in which you show how you access and use the data, once created, then we could maybe discuss about real-code optimization. (Btw, `xor` isn't standard: `ieor` is the intrinsic equivalent; `real*8` and `integer*8` were never standard; and in modern Fortran you can use `new_line`)

Comment: FYI, Gfortran now uses the very a related PRNG to this one *"The runtime-library implements the **xorshift1024** random number generator (RNG). This generator has a period of 2^{1024} - 1, and when using multiple threads up to 2^{512} threads can each generate 2^{512} random numbers before any aliasing occurs."* https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html

Comment: Also FYI, I am using the same PRNG as you, https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/eb5b54b9a8eb6af158a38038f72d07865fe23ee3/src/rng_par_zig.f90?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default It seems your version is slightly faster, but less universal (not parallel, and only uniform distribution). Anyway, I think the way I am converting the integer to the real number is better http://experilous.com/1/blog/post/perfect-fast-random-floating-point-numbers#half-open-range Be aware a problem in benchmarking, let the CPU spin-up first. The second attempt to generate the numbers is much faster!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only now I realized you are asking about this particular PRNG. I am using it in Fortran myself https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/eb5b54b9a8eb6af158a38038f72d07865fe23ee3/src/rng_par_zig.f90?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

My code in the link is slower than yours, because it calls several subroutines and aims to be more universal. Bet let's try to condense the code I use into a single subroutine.

So let's just compare the performance of your code and the optimized version by @SeverinPappadeux and my optimized code with Gfortran 4.8.5

```
> gfortran -cpp -O3 -mtune=native xoroshiro.f90 

 Time drand128 sub:   1.80900002    
 Time drand128 fun:   1.80900002    
 Time rng_uni:   1.32900000
```

the code is here, remember to let the CPU spin-up, the first iteration of the `k` loop is just garbage!!!

```
program test_xoroshiro128plus
   use iso_fortran_env       
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: n = 30000
   real*8  :: A(n,n)
   real*4  :: B(n,n)
   integer :: i, j, k, t0, t1, count_rate, count_max       

   integer(int64) :: s1 = int(Z'1DADBEEFBAADD0D0', int64), s2 = int(Z'5BADD0D0DEADBEEF', int64)

!let the CPU spin-up                                           
do k = 1, 3                                           
   call system_clock(t0, count_rate, count_max)
   do j = 1,n
      do i = 1,n
         call drand128(A(i,j))
      end do
   end do
   ! call drand128(A)  ! works also with 2D 
   call system_clock(t1)

   print *, "Time drand128 sub:", real(t1-t0)/count_rate

   call system_clock(t0, count_rate, count_max)
   do j = 1,n
      do i = 1,n
         A(i,j) = drand128_fun()
      end do
   end do
   ! call drand128(A)  ! works also with 2D 
   call system_clock(t1)

   print *, "Time drand128 fun:", real(t1-t0)/count_rate


   call system_clock(t0, count_rate, count_max)
   do j = 1,n
      do i = 1,n
         call rng_uni(A(i,j))
      end do
   end do
   call system_clock(t1)

   print *, "Time rng_uni:", real(t1-t0)/count_rate
end do

   print *, "Mean :", sum(A)/size(A), char(10), A(1:2,1:3)

 contains

   impure elemental subroutine drand128(r)
      real*8, intent(out) :: r
      integer*8 :: s0 = 113, s1 = 19937
      s1 = xor(s0,s1)
      s0 = xor(xor(ior(ishft(s0,55), ishft(s0,-9)),s1), ishft(s1,14))
      s1 = ior(ishft(s1,36), ishft(s1,-28))
      r = ishft(s0+s1, -1) / 9223372036854775808.d0
   end 

   impure elemental real*8 function drand128_fun()
     real*8, parameter :: c = 1.0d0/9223372036854775808.d0
     integer*8 :: s0 = 113, s1 = 19937
     s1 = xor(s0,s1)
     s0 = xor(xor(ior(ishft(s0,55), ishft(s0,-9)),s1), ishft(s1,14))
     s1 = ior(ishft(s1,36), ishft(s1,-28))
     drand128_fun = ishft(s0+s1, -1) * c
  end

  impure elemental subroutine rng_uni(fn_val)
    real(real64), intent(inout) ::  fn_val
    integer(int64) :: ival

    ival = s1 + s2

    s2 = ieor(s2, s1)
    s1 = ieor( ieor(rotl(s1, 24), s2), shiftl(s2, 16))
    s2 = rotl(s2, 37)    

    ival  = ior(int(Z'3FF0000000000000',int64), shiftr(ival, 12))
    fn_val = transfer(ival, 1.0_real64) - 1;    
  end subroutine

  function rotl(x, k)
    integer(int64) :: rotl
    integer(int64) :: x
    integer :: k

    rotl = ior( shiftl(x, k), shiftr(x, 64-k))
  end function    

end program
```

The main difference should come from the faster and better way to convert from integers to reals http://experilous.com/1/blog/post/perfect-fast-random-floating-point-numbers#half-open-range

If you are bored, you could try to inline `rotl()` manually, but I trust the compiler here.

Comment: Could you describe clearly platform and compiler (gfortran version) you're using? Because you might have better compiler which inlines differently etc

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I do not have anything special or new. gfortran 4.8.5 default in OpenSuse 42.3 and the CPU is i7-3770. I also tried Intel Fortran 16.0.1, sub and fun the same result 1.809s, rng_uni 1.176 s repeatably.

Comment: With gfortran 7 the original is better optimized to 1.465 s but again both sub and fun, rng_uni is 1.385 s.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my attempt. First, I made it to function - in x64 or similar ABI function returning float value do in in register - much faster than parameter transfer. Second, 
replaced final division by multiplication, though Intel compiler might do it for you.

Timing, Intel i7 6820, WSL, Ubuntu 18.04:

```
before -   0.850000024
after  -   0.601000011
```

GNU Fortran 7.3.0, command line

```
gfortran -std=gnu -O3 -ffast-math -mavx2 /mnt/c/Users/kkk/Documents/CPP/a.for
```

Code

```
  program test_xoroshiro128plus
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: n = 10000
  real*8  :: A(n,n)
  integer :: i, j, t0, t1, count_rate, count_max

  call system_clock(t0, count_rate, count_max)
  do j = 1,n
     do i = 1,n
        A(i,j) = drand128()
     end do
  end do
  A = drand128()  ! works also with 2D
  call system_clock(t1)

  print *, "Time :", real(t1-t0)/count_rate
  print *, "Mean :", sum(A)/size(A), char(10), A(1:2,1:3)

  contains

  impure elemental real*8 function drand128()
     real*8, parameter :: c = 1.0d0/9223372036854775808.d0
     integer*8 :: s0 = 113, s1 = 19937
     s1 = xor(s0,s1)
     s0 = xor(xor(ior(ishft(s0,55), ishft(s0,-9)),s1), ishft(s1,14))
     s1 = ior(ishft(s1,36), ishft(s1,-28))
     drand128 = ishft(s0+s1, -1) * c
  end

  end program
```

Comment: I do not see any difference in performance in my tests (see my answer). It seems these two perform in exactly the same way, did you check the optimized assembly? It seems quite easy to optimize this when inlining.

Comment: @VladimirF No, I didn't check the assembly, might do on weekend. Nevertheless, with settings I described and given OP original timing test, I clearly see the difference

Comment: Be sure to make some loop as I did, the CPU core must first realize the full speed is necessary. Only after that the speed comparison is meaningful.